# Filter User model using custom model

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I'm new to Django.
I have made a newletter app to send mails to those who subscribe to it.Hence,i have defined a model that extends User model.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    contact_number = models.CharField(max_length=10,null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
    subscribe_to_newsletter = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

How do i access the emails of those users who have subscribed to newsletter?I can't find a way to filter user and relate `User` and `UserProfile`.

Comment: You cannot relate which two models?

Comment: I was trying to filter across User model and the UserProfile model defined by me to extend user model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In django you can  [filter across relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) using `__`.
This will give you all users that have subscribed to the newsletter:

```
User.objects.filter(userprofile__subscribe_to_newsletter=True)
```

If you only want the emails you can uses `values_list`. This will give you a list of emails:

```
User.objects.filter(userprofile__subscribe_to_newsletter=True).values_list('email', flat=True)
```